# Trouble using VSFTPD service for ftp server on AWS S3

Tags: ftp, aws, amazon-ec2, vsftpd, amazon-linux

First post on here so I apologize if its in the wrong place or format.

So currently I have a working ftp server on aws linux EC2 and S3 with users that can connect via

ftp/ftps/sftp

. However the way I got it to work adds a few seemingly unnecessary steps for the client.

Directory setup:
`/home/username/ftp/files/Storage`

The user's home directory is configured to be at the 
`/home/username/ftp`
 level and the s3 is mounted on the /home/username/ftp/files level. In basic terms anything in 
`/home/username/ftp/files`
 and below is stored on the ec2 instance and anything 
`/home/username/ftp/files/Storage`
 and above is stored on the S3 bucket.

Issue I am having is when a user logs in, they are sent to the 
`/home/username/ftp`
 directory as their root directory and can go through files and Storage to eventually reach their data. I need them to land on 
`/home/username/ftp/files/Storage`
 in order to simplify their process.

Unfortunately any other home directory I have tried ends up sending me various errors.
Any ideas?

Thanks,
Tyler